# multi-table search filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I'm preparing to build a large multi-table backed site for the first time and was hoping the ruby community could help point me in the right direction on how to go about building this.

**About the app:** I have several large tables (>200k+ rows and 30 columns for each table).  Columns between each tables do not match, and if were to try and expand long to wide, and merge into one table, my total columns would balloon out of control.  So creating one master table is not a possibility in my mind. All of the tables's rows (observations) are connected through a unique_id.  What I looking to do, and where I was hoping to get some advise from the this community, is how I can create a multiple search criteria that can pull from various tables.

Here is a scaled down example of what I'm looking to accomplish.  In this example, we have table_1 and table_2 (both tables samples are below).  And let's say the users searches for name:*Tim* and subject: *English*, in order to see Tim's English grade: 78.

I've had no problems working with one table, but have never worked with multiple tables connected through one common identifier.  Again, remember that this is a scaled down version.  My actual tables are all very large and I cannot create one tables without my columns getting too large.

How would I go about insuring the filters are able to A: hold their selected variable, while B: the users searches other tables?  I hope I'm making myself clear here.  Thank you in advance for any pointers or advice to point me in the right direction.

```
TABLE_1         

Unique_ID   Name    Age     Sex
    1       Tim     16       Male
    2       Chris   15       Male
    3       Brad    18       Male
    4       Mary    20       Female


TABLE_2 

Unique_ID   Subject      Grade
    1        Math          88
    1        English       78
    1        History       98
    2        Math          65
    2        English       72
    2        History       84
```

Comment: You talk about databases, but your example looks like multiple tables in a database. Do you mean databases or tables? Is a view a possibility for your problem?

Comment: Yes, tables, you are correct.  I edited the question to reflect that change.

Comment: From your question, I take it you're new to Ruby on Rails?  Or do you already have models and migrations written for this application?  If you do, can you post a model relevant to your question?  Or are you looking for help in writing such a model and the relevant scopes?

Comment: Are you sure about your DB structure? You may define one flat table with three field: Unique_ID, fieldname and content. Perhaps you need a fourth field to store the data as String and Fixnum.

Comment: @rdnewman, thanks for your response.  I'm looking for direction on relevant scopes, not writing the model.  I can create models and throw search filters on one model.  But I've never created an app that would need one narrow search filter on multiple models.  This is where I need some direction and help.

Comment: I plan on creating the two models above and will publish the code.  Thank you.

Comment: Well, assuming table1 is a model named 'Student' and table2 is a model named 'Grade', then Grade would contain a FK named `student_id` (that holds the "Unique_ID" values you gave) and so could contain the line `belongs_to :student` and Student would contain the line `has_many :grades`.   Then you could just write `a = Student.find(<someid>); a.grades` to return the Grade records, or `a.grades.pluck(:grade)` to return just an array of the grades for that student.  Is that what you need?

Comment: based on my comment above, if you want to return a specific subject's grade, then i'd write `a.grades.subject('English')` and then in the Grade model, write `scope(:subject), ->(subject_name){where(subject: subject_name}`

Answer (score 0):

You may define a view to create a large table.

Example code (I use Sequel and SQLITE in my example. But AR will offers similar features):

```
#Prepare example
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.sqlite()
Sequel.extension :pretty_table

DB.create_table(:tab1){
  Fixnum :Unique_ID   
  String :Name    
  Fixnum :Age     
  String :Sex
}
DB[:tab1].insert(1, 'Tim', 16, 'Male')
DB[:tab1].insert(2, 'Chris', 15, 'Male')
DB[:tab1].insert(3, 'Brad', 18, 'Male')
DB[:tab1].insert(4, 'Mary', 20, 'Female')

DB.create_table(:tab2){
  Fixnum :Unique_ID   
  String :Subject
  Fixnum :Grade 
}

DB[:tab2].insert(1, 'Math', 88)
DB[:tab2].insert(1, 'English', 78)
DB[:tab2].insert(1, 'History', 98)
DB[:tab2].insert(2, 'Math', 65)
DB[:tab2].insert(2, 'English', 72)
DB[:tab2].insert(2, 'History', 84)


#Show how you could use a view to select on two tables
Sequel::PrettyTable.print(
  DB[:tab1].inner_join(:tab2, :Unique_ID => :Unique_ID).filter(:Name => 'Tim', :Subject => 'Math')
)
```

The result:

```
+---+-----+----+----+-------+---------+
|Age|Grade|Name|Sex |Subject|Unique_ID|
+---+-----+----+----+-------+---------+
| 16|   88|Tim |Male|Math   |        1|
+---+-----+----+----+-------+---------+
```

One problem is the big number of tables. So I would not recommend to create one big view with all data, nor to create many views.
You can define the join with the data you need for your selection.